# How To Add Multiple Buttons To UITableViewCells Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a simple iOS app with Xcode and Swift 5 where the user can pick a theme and then the background will change color. I want to accomplish this by adding buttons onto a table view's cells. I know how to add one button to a table view, but I have no idea how to put multiple buttons into a table view cell.

Here is a table view cell with a button I added to it:

[image]

p.s.: ignore the text inside of the button

What I'd want is for one button on each side and one in the middle, like this:

[image]

Here's my tableviewcontroller:

```swift
import UIKit

@objcMembers class TBController: UITableViewController {

    var times = 0
    var lastChar = ""
    var subString = ""
    var text = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return singleton.count
    }

    // 3
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        var cellButton: UIButton!
        ///////////////////
        cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30))//5, 5, 50, 30

        times = times + 1

        cell.textLabel?.text = SingletonViewController.singleton[indexPath.row]

        if times == 1{
            cellButton.setTitle("Back", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.addSubview(cellButton)
            cell.accessoryView = cellButton
            cellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            cell.tag = 1
        }else{
            cell.tag = 2
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I know how to add one button to a table view"* ... You need to show what you've done so far, so people can help you expand on that. Please review [ask].

Comment: @DonMag see my edits

Comment: Oh.... lots of stuff. 1) You want to use a custom cell.  2) Cells are reused, so don't ever add subviews (such as buttons) in `cellForRowAt` or you'll end up adding and re-adding them. 3) Use auto-layout instead of explicit frame values. 4) Start by searching for `swift custom table view cell` -- you'll find many, many tutorials, examples, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and create your own custom implementation, you can do this by code or by IB

This is the IB way of doing it:

When you create a new Cocoa Touch Class file, choose to subclass from UITableViewCell and select the create XIB file option. After that configure the XIB's view whoever you want and set a reuse identifier in the Identity Inspector.

If you want to have the layout from your screenshot, drag a `UIStackView`, set it's constraints to top, bottom, leading and trailing to the contentView of the cell, set the alignment to horizontal, then select `fill equally` and drag 3 `UIButton`s inside of it, the stackView will make sure to arrange them nicely

In your viewController don't forget to register the cell with the tableView, and then return that cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`